# Duplicate problem on Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, https, http

I use free hosting and a free site maker. After a while, I added my own domain via DNS settings. I faced a major problem after this. My new pages are not being indexed because Google detects duplicate pages.

I've made two property in Google Search Console with the new domain name and the old one because some links are at the top of search results and now I am afraid that by changing links I lost the position of google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Google that your new domain name is your canonical domain name for the content on the site, otherwise Google won’t index the new domain since it is duplicating content.

You can move to a new domain name by using 301 redirects from each page available on the old domain to the equivalent URL with the new domain. (Implementation of this depends on your web server.)

If you’re not able to set up redirects, or in addition to redirects, set the canonical tag at the top of each page to include the URL of the page using the new domain name.

Comment: from domain panel should i redirect to old page or there is other way?!

Comment: with redirect all pages comes with new domain name?? its nice

Comment: how make canonical tag?

Comment: The canonical tag is in your web pages, so needs to be set up with your free site maker (if possible). Redirects are also done on your side, your hosting can probably tell you how to do them on their system. Or you may be able to set up the redirects with the people you bought the domain from. They sometimes call it forwarding. Ask if they can do a site wide 301 redirects.